# Capturing and encrypting packets sent from Wildfly services

Tags: java, wildfly, packet-sniffers

I want to capture and encrypt the data for specific packets sent from Wildfly services. Is there a method to capture these packets?

Comment: you mean you want to write an app like wireshark by Java ?

Comment: @Mehdi I need to encrypt the data in the packet, which has a specific destination. but only for those sent from my Wildfly application server.

Comment: why not use SSL on your wildfly application server at the first place ?

Comment: @Mehdi I think that SSL does not provide point to point security. so, I need to use our encryption.